React app 'Encountered two children with the same key, `thumb-undefined`'
I'm trying to create a time slider in my react app and I can't beat this error below that keeps showing up in my browser console.
bundle.js:21658 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `thumb- 
undefined`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across 
updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the 
behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

I'm new to react and below is my code - any idea why this is happening?
                    <Card className="mb-3 border-0 shadow-sm">
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Form.Label className="fw-medium pb-2">Time Range</Form.Label>
                            <div className="px-2">
                                <Range
                                    values={timeRange}
                                    step={1}
                                    min={6}
                                    max={21}
                                    onChange={(values) => setTimeRange(values)}
                                    renderTrack={({ props, children }) => {
                                        const { key, ...restProps } = props;
                                        return (
                                            <div
                                                key={`track-${restProps['aria-valuemin']}-${restProps['aria-valuemax']}`}
                                                {...restProps}
                                                style={{
                                                    ...restProps.style,
                                                    height: '6px',
                                                    width: '100%',
                                                    backgroundColor: '#ddd'
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                {children}
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    }}
                                    renderThumb={({ props, isDragged }, idx) => {
                                        const { key, ...restProps } = props;
                                        return (
                                            <div
                                                key={`thumb-${idx}`}
                                                {...restProps}
                                                style={{
                                                    ...restProps.style,
                                                    height: '24px',
                                                    width: '24px',
                                                    borderRadius: '50%',
                                                    backgroundColor: 'var(--primary-color)',
                                                    display: 'flex',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    alignItems: 'center'
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <div
                                                    style={{
                                                        height: '16px',
                                                        width: '5px',
                                                        backgroundColor: isDragged ? 'var(--primary-color)' : '#CCC'
                                                    }}
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    }}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between mt-2">
                                <span>{`${timeRange[0] > 12 ? timeRange[0] - 12 : timeRange[0]}:00 ${timeRange[0] >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`}</span>
                                <span>{`${timeRange[1] > 12 ? timeRange[1] - 12 : timeRange[1]}:00 ${timeRange[1] >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`}</span>
                            </div>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>

I've tweaked the key...props several times and still can't get it to work. There are several questions on SO that have similar answers but my inexperience is struggling to map those answers to my code snippet. Any help would be appreciated.

you're accessing the index prop in the wrong way https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-range#renderthumb

In the renderThumb function, idx is undefined. In general, it is not good practice to use an index value in the key because it will change depending on the number of elements. Perhaps find another prop that is unique to that element and use that for the key.

Ah okay makes sense, thanks @spyguy. I'm referencing a static file but maybe I'll try adding fake _ids for each until they're in a db.

i wasnt sure what slider component you were using, but if its this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-range then you should do ({ props, isDragged,index }) => {...} instead of ({ props, isDragged }, idx) => {}

That was it @PhantomSpooks - thank you!
